# Safari force scroll

Tags: safari, css

```
html {overflow-y:
scroll;height:101%;overflow-y:hidden;}
```

To force scrolling, when I view one my sites on my Mobile phone the bottom gets cut off, but looks fine in FirefoxF/IE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to say:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

but I would also try

```
body { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: Hey I tried that and the url is here: http://www.catonthecouchproductions.com/fish

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow-y:hidden;` would clip the contents that exceed the size of the element. The default should be automatic to allow scrolling but setting it to `overflow-y:scroll;` or `overflow:scroll;` (which would allow vertical and horizontal scrolling) should make it work.